# How to get undetected-chromedriver working in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Does anyone know how to get undetected chrome driver working in nodeJS? This is a python library but I'd like to code in NodeJs and target the browser of this library.
https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

My attempt was to put the undetected-chromedriver.exe file in the root of my project and target that inside my nodejs project. However it did not work or I was doing it incorrectly. Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
 // Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
  const chromeDriverPath = 'undetected_chromedriver.exe';

// Set Chrome options if needed (e.g., to run headless)
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe');

// chromeOptions.addArguments('--headless'); // Uncomment this line to run Chrome in headless mode

// Create a new Chrome WebDriver instance
const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .setChromeService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromeDriverPath))
    .build();
```

Comment: Where did you find the `undetected-chromedriver.exe` file ?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii AppData\Roaming\undetected_chromedriver\undetected_chromedriver.exe     .. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii  do you have a discord username i can msg you at? I see you are familiar with this and might be able to help me. I am pretty desperate :D

Comment: Yeah, ofc you can use the patched driver executable from __undetected-chromedriver__, but that won't solve all detectability issues

Comment: => undetected-chomedriver doesn't exist for NodeJs yet. My discord is `/╲/\╭(•‿•)╮/\╱\#3208`

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Oh ok thats good to know. Guess I'll stick to python then. Added you if that username isn't a troll :D

Answer (score 0):

The full script is working, if you put the full part of the undetected_chromedriver.exe path. Also, I obviously use Windows.

```
// Here you import modules
const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

// Here you set the path
const chromeDriverPath = 'C:\\Users\\myaccount\\AppData\\Roaming\\undetected_chromedriver\\undetected_chromedriver.exe';

// here you set Chrome options
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe');
// chromeOptions.addArguments('--headless'); // Uncomment this line to run Chrome in headless mode

// here creating new Chrome WebDriver instance
const driver = new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .setChromeService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromeDriverPath))
    .build();

// here you navigate to a website
async function exampleScript() {
    try {
        // nav
        await driver.get('https://www.example.com');

        // sleep for 60 seconds to check if script was successful
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
        
        // close
        await driver.quit();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
    }
}

// call the main function
exampleScript();
```

You have to "npm install selenium-webdriver" before. But I tried on a website with a lot of bot protection and it failed. The "official" undetected_chromedriver.exe is being monitored, so the better question is to build/patch a new undetected_chromedriver.exe for every computer.

Comment: On Linux, I get the error "Error: spawn /home/user/.local/share/undetected_chromedriver/ EACCES". If I execute the binary directly and connect remotely to the port, the browser is launched but I can see that `navigator.webdriver` is still set to true instead of false to avoid detection. So it looks like the binary is unpatched by default and I guess we need to start undetected-chromedriver using Python so it apply the patches, there is a known issue: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/821.

Comment: This EACCES error, it seems that this is as file permission issue related to your Linux set-up (Try running with super user? Try chmod +x before? Etc), but this is not an undetected_chromedriver issue related to the original question in the sense of whether or not the code works. For the given link, thank you very much, I thought I read somewhere that one can also manually patch the original chromedriver, so I proposed this solution that can be viable also. Anyway there must be a way to launch it with Node.js in the same manner as Python if we pass the correct command line (it's onły a binary)

Comment: I took a moment to test the script again and the issue was due to the path you can see in my previous comment (I forgot to add the binary name undetected_chromedriver at the end). By the way, running a web browser as root is not recommend for security. But we can see that `navigator.webdriver` is still set to `true` which means the binary is unpatched and it looks like the patch can be applied by running the Python code like in the issue I mentioned before (but there is another issue that I mentioned in the GitHub issue).